# Dojo - dijit.dialog

Tags: dojo, dialog

Here's the flow of my problem:
I have one modal dialog, when I open a new dialog, it would open contentOne.jsp inside the modal dialog.  When I click on a link on contentOne.jsp, the modal dialog refreshes and open contentTwo.jsp with my href reference.  Then I close the dialog.  When I open the dialog again, it would open contentTwo.jsp not contentOne.jsp.  I tried destroyDescendants, destroyRendering.... but they didn't work.

I have a header that has a link to open a modal dialog like the following:

```
<div style="position: relative;right: 50px; top: 15px;">
     <a onclick="dijit.byId('selectEquipmentInfo').show(); return false;"            href=""       />Add Equipment</a>

</div>
<%-- start equipment info dialog link --%>
    <div id="selectEquipmentInfo" style="display:none;" name="selectEquipmentInfo" dojotype="dijit.Dialog" draggable="false" title="Select Equipment">
    <div style="width:870px; height:400px; padding: 10px; overflow-y:auto;" href="">
         <%@ include file="../../StoreInfoArea/ProductFamilyDisplay.jspf"%>

    </div>
    </div>
```

This should open a modal dialog.  Inside my ProductFamilyDisplay.jspf, I have an item linked to another jsp page on 'href' like the following

```
 <div id="productFamily" class="productFamilyContainer">
<div id= "prdctFamilyRow" class="productFamilyColumn">
<c:forEach  var="equipmentInfo"    items="${equipmentTestList}" varStatus="status">
<a href="${EquipmentModelsViewURL}"><c:out value="${equipmentInfo.value}" /></a><br />

    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

This will render on the same modal dialog, and it's being controlled by this javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
dojo.addOnLoad (function(event){
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId('selectEquipmentInfo'), 'onClick', clicked);
});

   var clicked=function(event) {



        var dialog=dijit.byId('selectEquipmentInfo');
        var contentNode=dialog.domNode;
        var node = event.target;
        var attrId = dojo.attr(node, "id");

        if (attrId =="dijitCloseLink" || attrId == "dijitCloseImg") {
            dialog.set('href','');



        } else {
        if("a" == node.nodeName.toLowerCase()){
            dialog.href=node.href;
            dialog.refresh();
            dojo.stopEvent(event);
        } 
        }
    };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to locate code to destroy the Dialog. Try given below code. Put this code in the div where you are creating the dialog.

```
   dojo.connect(selectEquipmentInfo, "hide", function(e){
                dijit.byId("selectEquipmentInfo").destroy(); 
            });
```

Comment: Hello, using .destroy() basically destroys the whole dialog.  When I click on 'Select Equipment' again, it doesn't work because this code    dijit.byId('selectEquipmentInfo').show(); causes an error.  'selectEquipmentInfo' is undefined.

Comment: Your code to create Dialog need to be invoked again in that case.